# Yiddish Song on Purim

Tags: purim, song-poetry, yiddish

My family sings a song on Purim that I am trying to track down. It is mostly Yiddish, with a little bit of Hebrew. The song starts with

```
פֿאַרוואָס זאָגט די תורה האָב נישט קיין מורא
```

and ends with

```
מחה תמחה את זכר עמלק
```

The song is obviously (from those lyrics) Jewish in content. Does anyone know what the title of the song is, and what the full lyrics are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [forum post](https://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92016&sid=6a21128273ec8452d36cea19b9d3dfde#p92016) here, the song is called "גראמען לכבוד חדש אדר" - "Rhymes in honor of the month of Adar" ("Gramen" means "rhymes" in Yiddish) and these are the lyrics:

```
גראמען לכבוד חדש אדר  
  
לכבוד פורים קודש  
לכבוד דעם הייליגען חודש  
חודש אדר שמרבים בו בשמחה  
  
וועל איך זינגען א זמר  
לקיים מה שנאמר  
את זכר עמלק מחה תמחה  
  
דאס ווייסט דאך יעדער מסתמא  
אז דאס איז די גרויסע מלחמה  
מלחמה לד' בעמלק מדור דור  
  
דער מלחמה איז פאר אונז טייער  
אין יעדען דור א רשע א נייע  
אבער בכל מושבותיכם יהי' אור  
  
אויף דעם זאגט די תורה  
האב פאר קיינעם מורא  
די זאלסט אויף אים מאכן א סטרייק  
  
געדענק דעם אלטען תרח  
אשר קרך בדרך  
מחה תמחה את זכר עמלק  
  
***********************************  
  
  
די מעשה איז נישט קיין נייעס  
מ'ווייסט דאך עמלק'ס דיעות  
געוואלט אריין ברענגען אין אונז דאס קרירות  
  
יום ליום יביע אומר  
כביכול איז אונזער שומר  
אלמלא הקב"ה שומרו מיר דארפען גרויסע שמירות  
  
ווער ווייסט דען נישט די פשט  
אשר קרך איז נישט אזוי גלאט  
עמלק האט אונז געוואלט קאלט מאכן  
  
עס איז אים נישט געלונגען  
ווייל אידן לאזן זיך נישט צווינגען  
אידן לאכן זיך אויס פון די אלע זאכן  
  
אויף דעם זאגט די תורה  
האב פאר קיינעם מורא  
האלט דיך פעסט געב דיך נישט קיין בייג  
  
היט נאר דעם אלטען דרך  
דעם הייליגע ערך  
און מחה תמחה את זכר עמלק  
  
  
************************************  
  
  
מיר האבן אויך דערלעבט  
עס האט קין סאך נישט געפעלט  
די זעלבע מעשה מיט המן האבן מיר מיט געמאכט  
  
דאס קען מען נישט פארזעהן  
עס איז אזא בראך געשען  
מ'האט פון אונז צוגענומען א דור א פראכט  
  
מיר זענען געבליבן א שארית  
א קליין ביסעלע נירות  
פון דעם מוז זיך דערוועקן א גרויסע אור  
  
קימו מה שקיבלו כבר  
ויחן ישראל נגד ההר  
אפי' נאך אזא גרויסע דור  
  
אויף דעם זאגט די תורה  
ליהודים היתה אורה  
חזק חזק ונתחזק  
  
עס וועט זיין פלאי פלאים  
ארורים כל הרשעים  
מחה תמחה את זכר עמלק  
  
  
**************************************  
  
  
דער שטן דעם עמלק  
מוז מען לערנען בלק  
אזוי ווערט אנגערופען דעם יצר הרע  
  
מיט זיין קרויסע גיאות  
קומט ער מיט קרומע דיעות  
אנשטאט א חסיד'ישע רקידה טאנצט מען א הארע  
  
ליידער אפי' אין ארץ ישראל  
אפיקורסות איבעראל  
עמלק דרייט זיך פריי אין אלע גאסן  
  
דאס איז אים נאך צי ווייניג  
אלץ מוז עם זיין אייניג  
די קליינע שעפעלעך פארכאפט ער אין די מאסן  
  
אויף דעם זאגט די תורה  
האב פאר קיינעם מורא  
מלחמת עמלק איז קיין דבר ריק  
  
כל החוסים בך  
זענען מצווה בלא תשכח  
מחה תמחה את זכר עמלק
```

I should note that the phrase you wrote doesn't appear as-is in the song. Instead what's written here is "אויף דעם זאגט די תורה האב פאר קיינעם מורא", which is similar, but not exactly the same. Likely, your family simply has a different version of the song.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've been looking for this for ages.

Comment: @magicker72 Thank you for the edit. I'm not that good with either Yiddish or with the programming in SE.